# Assistance with specific sed command

Tags: linux, sed

pretty new to linux and am really struggling to understand what this command will do even after extensive research, any help or explanation will be greatly appreciated

```
sed -n 's/[A-Z]/&e/gp'
```

Answer (score 2):

`[A-Z]` will match any uppercase character.  `&` prints what is matched.  `&e` prints each uppercase matched letter with an `e` appended.  Look at the following example:

```
$ echo "Hello There" | sed -n 's/[A-Z]/&e/gp'
Heello Tehere
$
```

`-n` suppresses automatic printing while `p` at the end of statement `gp` prints what is changed.  `g` in `gp` applies the change to each occurrence of the matched pattern on the line, for example the two instances of uppercase letters in the example.